# List to comma-separated string values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, string

I have a list

```
['a','b','c']
```

I would like

```
'a','b','c'
```

I've tried

```
"','".join(tst)
```

but it returns a string

```
"a','b','c"
```

I need it in the format

```
'a','b','c'
```

for input to a function, can anyone suggest how to do this?

Comment: Do you need to pass the list elements to a function? Please check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Add the single quote at the beginning and at the end:

```
"'"+"','".join(tst)+"'"
```

Comment: This is not what the user wants. he does not want a string!

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
str(['a','b','c']).strip('[]')
```

Comment: Or `str(l)[1:-1]` in case the contained string have brackets in them

Comment: This is not what the user wants. he does not want a string!

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple, you just need to unpack the list with the star `*` operator:

```
def f(a, b, c):
    print(a)
    print(b)
    print(c)

f(*['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

This will correctly prints

```
a
b
c
```